# Rule driven user interface rendering techniques/framework for a web applciation

Tags: user-interface, workflow

I am in process of designing web application which should address below primary requirement -

> User interface should be rendered dynamically upon user actions and business rule associated with it.

For example - consider set of users as U1, U2, U3. consider set of roles as Role1, Role2 and Role3 with mapping as below :

```
U1 --> (Role1) 
U2 --> (Role1 and Rol3) 
U3 --> (Role2)
```

There would be set of business rules associated with user operations such as :

```
If U1 logs in on screen1 and enters amount > 1000 --> disable dropdown list and submit button on screen1
If U1 logs in on screen2 and enters derived amount < 5000 --> enable submit button on screen2
```

I tried evaluating DROOLS for this requirement; seems need to build custom component which will use these rules, user roles and then return set of UI components which needs to rendered on the user interface.

Can anyone suggest a better approach?